# How to set specific checkboxes checked with JQuery by checking the value of its "ID" and the value of its "value" attribute?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

first of all this is my first post so maybe the whole description may be a bit bulky, sorry for that. Usually i am not asking for help but i am having a hard time on this one.

Ok so , I want by taking the values of a php's response with jQuery to change to 'checked' the appropriate checkboxes where : "id=" the "cat_id" and "value=" the "attr_id".
Each checkbox on our html has two "parameters" .A "value" attribute which is assigned the attr_id (primary key of one of the db tables) and an "ID" attribute which is assigned with the cat_id (primary key of another table)

Now , what the php function does? Is looking in a Mysql table and taking the result of another table in which attr_id and cat_id are entries of two foreign keys reffering to the above table.The response of the php looks like this :

**Wrong:**
Use of the same ids for multiple divs instead of classes

```
<div id='keys'><div id='key'><div id='att_id'>53</div><div id='ca_id'>1</div></div><div id='key'><div id='att_id'>50</div><div id='ca_id'>1</div></div></div>
```

**Correct:**

```
<div id='keys'><div class='key'><div class='att_id'>53</div><div class='ca_id'>1</div></div><div class='key'><div class='att_id'>50</div><div class='ca_id'>1</div></div></div>
```

You can easily imagine it as an XML-like structure.

So after echoing the response back to JQuery, Jquery have to find the checkboxes with these "parameters" and make them checked

The code for how the JQuery is taking the values and trying to change the specific checkboxes with attr_id and cat_id equal to these we received from php's response is below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data='?action=showkeys&val=true';
  var url="admin-ajax.php";
  url=url+data;
  checkBrowser();
if(xmlhttp != null){
    xmlhttp.open("POST",url);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 || xmlhttp.readyState=="complete") {
    var response=xmlhttp.responseText.slice(0,-1);
    $(response).find("div.key").each(function(){
    var attrid=$(this).find("div.att_id").text();
    var catid=$(this).find("div.ca_id").text();  //use of classes
    $("."+catid+"[value="+attrid+"]").attr("checked", true); //correct command
        });
    }
  }
});
```

Now i think the problem is that i cant choose the checkbox i want . meaning that the last line of my code :

```
$('input:checkbox#'+catid+'[value="'+attrid+'"]').attr('checked',true);
```

must be wrong . cause if i am watching in firebug that the response has been send correctly and if i ll try to write the values i retrieved in a part of the html i can see that indeed i took the values in the JQuery variables catid and attrid.

All in all : I want to find the checkbox which has a specific value and specific ID and make it checked. Now if checking what is the value is too hard i could assign the value's variable as checkboxe's class.

Thank you in advance.

----SOLVED-----

Comment: why not use jquery's get or post functions instead of crafting your ajax call by hand?

Comment: also im not sure what you want to achieve with $('input:checkbox#'+catid).val(attrid).attr('checked','checked'). can you try to make your question a bit more clearer?

Comment: Ok all i want to do is that. find a checkbox with specific value and specific id and make it checked. i think i will create a new answer on my question and explain it better.
I tried this:
$('input:checkbox#'+catid+'[value="'+attrid+'"]').attr('checked',true);
 , which i think now is totaly correct but then the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I tried to be more specific. i edited my post and i made with bold the important points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about

```
$("#"+catid).attr("value", attrid).attr("checked", true);
```

you don't need to specify the input checkbox since your element ids must be unique anyway

Comment: also, why return a block of divs like that? it would be easier for you if you made the return value a JSON string

Comment: Now i cant answer you on this, i guess because i came up with this solution on my mind at this time. I wanted to send xml document as response but there where some other issues so it made sense to me to mask xml in html. The answer you gave is correct, indeed it marks the checkbox , but for example in response i have parameters for two checkbox (<div id='key'>) and only one is marked. I guess there is some kind of mistake in the loop i m doing above in .each() . What i tried to say to jquery was, find all divs with id=key (2) and for each take the inner divs' text & check the right checkboxes.

Comment: declaring an id twice is not allowed, that's why it's called an id. if you want "key" to be declared more than once, then use class.

Comment: still the same, my loop : $(response).find("div.key").each(function(){
   var attrid=$(this).find("div.att_id").text();
    var catid=$(this).find("div.ca_id").text();
}  
seems correct?

Comment: ca_id is a typo? and you also need to make att_id into a class( i mean the html output of your php should be class="key" and class="att_id"

Comment: no is not a typo, take a look at the response, i already did it as class but somewhere is is the issue. if i ll remove find('div.key') and writte on my JQuery $(response).each(function(){
var attrid=$(this).find("div.att_id").text();

var catid=$(this).find("div.ca_id").text(); }      Is returning both the values but as a combined string, instead of attrid to take the value 1 two times is taking the value 11 one time and catid instead of taking the values 50 , 51 is taking the value "5051"

Comment: Ok done it , thnx a lot for directions, if you werent you i would never think that ids are the fault and i had to make them classes. so i ll edit my original post to the working one and thats all! :)  Thnx a lot !